# stm32 custom bootloader flashed same code behaves different

Tags: assembly, bootloader, stm32, flash-memory

So I'm writing my bootloader for stm32f103vet6. My map file

```
"A1":  place at 0x08000000 { ro section .intvec };
"P1":  place in [from 0x08000000 to 0x0801ffff] { ro };
"P2":  place in [from 0x20000000 to 0x20013fff] { rw, block CSTACK, block HEAP };
"P3":  place in [from 0x08020000 to 0x080fffff] { section .REWRITESTUFF };
```

I'm rewriting code in P3 section. I am trying to bootload same program. It works fine after restart but fails during simple gpio init call. `stdperiph` code is placed in P1 section and is not touched during flashing, so gpio init function is working. also it fails after several calls of this function.

[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBuZY.jpg)
[image]

In image on the left is the code after bootloading. On the right is before. It looks the same, but for some reason behaves differently. After that bootloaded code goes the wrong way and falls into hardfault.

It looks like it can't get to the right function (but it was possible just several lines before) and instead of that goes the wrong way. Flashed bytes are ok at least at this place so  I dont know what to do next.

Comment: Obviously there must be some difference. What do you see around address `0x8021400` in the "right" version ?

Comment: As it usually happens I found the error, I was sending the slightly wrong data and was not able to see it during this mistake. Now it works :)